# Stringifying date causes timezone change

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am stringifying an object which contains `moment` object. It changes the timezone. How do I preserve the time zone even after stringifying the object.

`localStorage.setItem("energy_meter", JSON.stringify(localStorageObj));`

```
localStorageObj.ltg.push({
            ltgId: message["topic"].split('/')[1],
            time: (moment()),
            message: message.payloadString,
            floorNo: message["topic"].split('/')[2] || null
        })
```

That is the object I am stringifying.

Answer (score 0):

```
date = new Date();
let hours = date.getHours() - date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
let minutes = (date.getHours() - date.getTimezoneOffset()) % 60;
date.setHours(hours);
date.setMinutes(minutes);
```